# Find a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which preserves angles but does not preserve the norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which preserves angles but does not preserve the norm

Any suggestions?

Thanks for help me :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider scalar multiplication.

Comment: Can be $T(x)=2x$ ??

Comment: @user63192 Yes that's a good example.